# BitLocker with TPM 2.0 chip - Is it possible to decrypt the drives using Recovery Keys?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, bitlocker

I'm having a new laptop Dell Inspiron 7577-92774 equipped with TPM 2.0 chip. System: Win10 Pro.

I have encrypted both of the internal drives with BitLocker under the new scheme.

I used Linux before, and I don't know much about BitLocker, so... straight to the question:

If the laptop died, for example motherboard issue, and I would be forced to carve the drives out, would I be able to decrypt the drives using the Recovery Keys on another computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft's [`repair-bde` manual page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/repair-bde), I quote:

> Repair-bde can reconstruct critical parts of the drive and salvage recoverable data as long as a valid recovery password or recovery key is used to decrypt the data.

It should be possible without problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recovery key, you can be relaxed. 
After you changed the motherboard, then it will bring you to a recovery mode, where you should enter the recovery key.
Since you used Bitlocker to encrypted the drive, it will scan for changes during boot up.
If you encounter some problems when you decrypt the drives, you can refer to:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2010/08/04/issues-resulting-in-bitlocker-recovery-mode-and-their-resolution/

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18671.bitlocker-troubleshooting-continuous-reboot-loop-with-bitlocker-recovery-on-a-slate-device.aspx